# Tensorflow vs Python

Tags: tensorflow

I'm not an expert in this domain so far. I am a web developer, and I am using rather Python and MySQL as programming language. I've heard about TensorFlow. What are the advantages of Tensorflow compared to Python? What is the use of Tensorflow?

**EDIT :** 
I know TensorFlow is a machine learning framework. What is the advantage of using that framework instead of another one?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you should accept [@Rehaan's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42429580/3941813) answer since he answered your original question. The question you added after the edit should be asked in another post but it probably will not be well received since it is open to subjective judgement. I recommend you to study the other available frameworks a little and see which one is better suited to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TensorFlow isn't a programming language, it is a machine learning framework and python is one of the languages it supports. You can't really compare tensorflow and python. Python is a language.